# remotely shutting down a linux computer when no user is logged in

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement, ssh

I wrote a small script to update a number of Linux computers daily (among other things, which is why a cron job will not do).
It is meant to run at night and ssh into each client, update it and shut it down if no other user is logged in. The solution I've come up with is this:

```
ssh "$value" 'apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && if [ $(who | wc -l) != 1 ] ; then exit; else poweroff; fi;' >> "/var/log/updates/$value.log"
```

When running the script I get Syntax error near unexpected token 'then'.
Any help is appreciated

Edit: I am aware what a cronjob is and how to set it up.
Here is why a cronjob will not do:

- Not all users leave their PCs on when they leave. So I will have to use WOL to start them at night. WOL -> cron seems pointless, if the client does not wake up in time.
- This should be done at night so no work is disrupted in case a reboot is needed.
- If I want to install a specific tool on all PCs I use this script as well.
- The Fix suggested below does not solve the Syntax problem. It will not shutdown the PC either.

Comment: What about `batch` or `at` jobs running at night?

Comment: As I've said, I would use a cronjob for that. But however, the command syntax should basically work. I cannot reproduce the syntax error. Are you sure that you didn't accidentally entered some problematic hidden chars? Try to type the command again.

Comment: I just retyped it. no change.

Comment: @KlausSteinhauer The command is working for me. Are you sure that `bash` is the default shell on the remote machine?

Comment: A cron job won't start on a powered off machine

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch With systemd.timer units and hardware support, it definitely is possible. Aside from that, using systemd.timer units with ``OnCalendar`` and ``Persistent=true`` would also fix that.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch What do you mean?

Comment: `crond` needs a computer to run. and it is the process starting `cron` jobs..

Answer (score 0):

No need to ssh to each client.you can add below cronjob to every client as below

cronjob add to every day 00.00 midnight (run this root or sudo user)

```
crontab -e
```

add:

```
0 0 * * * root sh /home/user/run.sh
```

eg:01 with &&

```
cat run.sh

apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && if [ $(who | wc -l) != 1 ] ; then exit; else poweroff; fi;' >> "/var/log/updates/$value.log"
```

if one of the commands fails, then all other commands following it won't be executed.

If you want to execute all commands regardless of whether the previous ones failed or not, separate them with semicolons:

eg:02 with ; command

```
cat run.sh

apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade ; if [ $(who | wc -l) != 1 ] ; then exit; else poweroff; fi;' >> "/var/log/updates/$value.log"
```

Comment: I guess he wants to run that at night, not at noon.

Comment: sorry but conjobs work @night ..change the content in properwayt